# Why does typescript "forget" generic constraint inside function?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

A simple example of what I mean:

```js
    type Shape = 'square' | 'circle';
    type Params<S extends Shape> = S extends 'square' ? { side: number } : { radius: number };

    function getArea<S extends Shape>(shape: S, params: Params<S>) {
      switch (shape) {
        // I need to tell TS the type of Param otherwise it complains that
        // params can be either { side: number } or { radius: number }.
        case 'square': return Math.pow((params as Params<'square'>).side, 2);
        case 'circle': return (params as Params<'circle'>).radius * Math.PI;
        // I also need to add a default case because TS complains that not all code paths return a value.
        default: return -1;
      }
    }
    // But interestingly, when I call the function, TS correctly applies the
    // generic constraint. So this results in error:
    getArea('square', { radius: 1 }) // It correctly says that { radius: 1 } is not assignable to { side: number }.
```

Because of the need to add the default case, I assume that `<S extends Shape>` makes the generic type `S` not simply `S` but something else. But when I experimented calling `getArea` with non-`Shape` shape parameter, I got a correct error that the argument not assignable to the type `Shape`.

So from the outside of the function, TS correctly understands that the param 'shape' needs to be of type `Shape` and the param 'params' needs to be the correct Params type.
But from inside the function, TS doesn't know that 'shape' is of type `Shape` and also don't know that params is of the type `Params<typeof shape>`.

Comment: I would guess because the call to `getArea('square', ...)` selects `getArea<'square'>('square', ...)` whereas a conditional within the function does not have an effect on the template that gets selected. Even changing `params: Params<S>` to `params: S` does not change the type of `params` in the conditional (when I hover over the variable).

Comment: `S` can be the full union so `getArea(Math.random() < 0.999 ? "square" : "circle", { radius: 2 })` is a valid call; there's no way to say "`S` must be exactly one union member" (that's requested at [ms/TS#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808)) and so TS doesn't even try to narrow *type parameters* based on control flow analysis (that's requested at [ms/TS#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014)). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I believe this is a limitation of TypeScript, which could be addressed using discriminated unions: https://tsplay.dev/N9j0qm

Comment: Thanks @jcalz, your answer fully answer my question.

Comment: Okay I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript currently doesn't have a way to say that a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) must be specified with a type argument corresponding to *exactly one* of the union members.  It is always possible to specify any subtype of the union, including the full union itself.  So this is allowed:

```
getArea(
    Math.random() < 0.999 ? "square" : "circle",
    { radius: 1 }
); // okay

/* function getArea<"square" | "circle">(
    shape: "square" | "circle", 
    params: { side: number; } | { radius: number; }
): number */
```

Here `S` is specified with the full union `"square" | "circle"`, inferred from the `shape` argument which is of that union type.  And therefore `params` is also allowed to be of a union type `{ side: number } | { radius: number }`.  In that call, there's a 99.9% chance that you've passed in `"square"` and a `Params<"circle">`, which is why inside the function the compiler warns you.

Well, actually, the compiler warns you because it *never* uses [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) to narrow or re-constrain a generic type parameter like `S` inside of function bodies.  You can narrow the type of `shape`, but `S` itself will stay stubbornly the same.  So even if you could manage to write a generic call signature that was guaranteed to be safe, the compiler would still fail to notice inside the function body.

So that's why it's happening.

---

There are several related open feature requests in GitHub looking for an improvement here.

One is [microsoft/TypeScript#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808), which would allow you to say that `S` could only be specified with *one* union member of `Shape`, so that a call as shown above with `S` being `Shape` would be disallowed.

Another is [microsoft/TypeScript#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014), which would allow type parameters to be narrowed via control flow analysis.  It kind of depends on something like the other feature being implemented also.  So if `shape` were `"square"`, then the other feature would ensure that `S` had to be `"square"`, and so this feature would then reconstrain `S` to `"square"`, and then the compiler could understand that `params` is `Params<"square">` and you could reference its `side` property.

So if both of those were implemented, maybe you could write:

```
// THIS IS NOT VALID TS as of TS 5.0!!
function getArea<S extends_oneof Shape>(shape: S, params: Params<S>) {
    switch (shape) {
        case 'square': return Math.pow(params.side, 2);
        case 'circle': return params.radius * Math.PI;
    }
}
```

and everything would be fine.

---

For now you just can't use generics this way.  You could, for this example, refactor to using a [destructured discriminated union](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6/#cfa-destructured-discriminated-unions) instead, as mentioned [in @vr.'s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75835512/why-does-typescript-forget-generic-constraint-inside-function?noredirect=1#comment133769258_75835512):

```
function getArea(...[shape, params]:
    ["circle", { radius: number }] | ["square", { side: number }]
) {
    switch (shape) {
        case 'square': return Math.pow(params.side, 2);
        case 'circle': return params.radius * Math.PI;
    }
}
getArea('square', { radius: 1 }) // error
getArea(
    Math.random() < 0.999 ? "square" : "circle",
    { radius: 1 }
); // error
```

But explaining exactly how and why that works is outside the scope of the question as asked.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAygFgQ0lAvFA5AZwI4FcEBOE6UAPhgMYCWBFANsQNwBQoyACoQgLaYA8MKBAAewCADsAJpliJIAPlSwhoidIw58REgH4oAbyiYqkiAC4o43NwBGEAlAC+UC4YIJJVXJgtXb9pxZmADNccQpgKgB7cSgAcwhgAEEiBAEVMSkZeCQIeQAKTDlzWAAaKDAuXgtOd14BeQBKA2YoNqMAdypgCjgoQuLm-Vb20YB6MagASUsICEkoYCjFiDo6KAAVQWA4aDZoKOCoWp4oKJ37LsxobqgKKO4wOgQqcRkdhGAR0baJiqqZBQELE7EJursHIZjKZfNY7A5nFFIVB3J5vLD-AiAHTfH5A64aPCEYgWIjAXAEWIAWU+cCxYCiHXy+UqdRkCBkJ3qWCJ2iaWOhEHKACZGiwfu18dB0NRaAx0KTEhTYiyAVAOccAXwZTR6MR+aivDIAFRQGk7LHsKbiiVQP4zBB0TDLcRzBZLdWSBYIKCmYIIXB0YB3DnQOxA7zQLZ3B5PF5vRaIYPic7qtYx0z-HYyMnK9VQABujtwEBxtt9EH9geAivJlKgAFoAIw2tqOZjtv4AIVwwdeYiImEi4jidBA5Q6u1iMyB6YuUFC4UiMXK0fuBCIETH6rATyoEHeu2YfwSroIVAoMbewHc-axsGWOyoOYP1ZkryEG6RZmYCWSqXyHktGIco3A8I0LCbJxmntYN103YBt0wBAQEPT4DBRcD0SgKDnGfSxUw5Yw4nEBAbAYRZlihEwSj8eEoGYRi-xSCAEHyXFzTpdwpAefJmj4KAAAYsQATjEqA9AAIk0YlJJcKBJNlPVJNKXEwLRHwcKcZgxTtSYogAaxQxixlNRcImiWJmNSPhpN5CA5PIRTdQYSSClxIpcgsOzgMchSlNc8pcVZHhNOomFLDhexGCcMgMMNbC6Oi7TGgxejjTGRjSO4A9KgoaAADlzgANUdEwWnGSYCoAeQ2KBiqSAAZKYABFNhgcoWuqgr0DqgB1AAlKYNgAUU2AAJKYYFxUzcXM5crMSFi0kEERMmkAB9GIIEOWRcgKTzIAsDr-jZGotRgJoKttTAuh6PoBlyIZcXLe1ZnmSiVnTaN532M4ji5M4LgIK4bjg2NnleNCvnLSrTtCkMQWgCBwQCcLaKihEzmRBLNKS7EXttKVCWAhUUSVetOPpRlVTZAUaJFMVCYlYmdTlElybrWIQt4LFcagU0qatVtYbex1nXe91lg8b0KyrIMQwJcMAwJNcIfjaGCODR11nuTNKmzTm8x9Is6BLMtYbaP0AyDWs82bEXRnbJ3cQymbJh7PtxAHA8vnbZhstyhB8qgFrnwoc9uAAVRaOawgsmJ4iWgCsVTgBtQ6hXh3gAF0f3LNPnPZlT4qwvHMacHO4sLmSiBL9G0oCRwc+e8tbu6Xp+kz1vLcV6Va453NKdpammR5zB6dMRnHaJ0NKBcweKe5gE+bLgWzRH4Xme0l3Rms1jAIH9BQMwjTIOgvTPwIJFcX3tjt6p7jJF4-ihNE8SpIHuTvIChzVPLdSEEtLO3aLpP49hr4EA7EAA)